# Find identical observations in a column´s data frame but different in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, I have a data frame which includes a ID column. I need to find all the rows that have the same ID but are different in the X1 variable.

For example,

```
d

ID    X1     X2
a    19      F
b    19      F
c    16      T
a    16      T 
a    19      T
d    17      T 
b    15      F 
b    19      F
c    17      T
c    17      T
d    17      T
e    15      T
f    14      T
g    16      T
```

The result will be:

```
df1

ID    X1     X2
a    19      F
b    19      F
c    16      T
a    16      T 
b    15      F 
c    17      T
```

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share data in the future for ease of reproduction

Comment: Why is `d 17` not included in the result?

Comment: Because d have the same value in X1.

Comment: How is `a 19` included? `19` appears twice for `a`, isn't it?

Comment: Why between `a 19 T` and `a 19 F`, the latter is selected? what's the reason? I think the question is vacuous

Comment: @RonakShah a 19 is included because a 17 is in the data frame.  I am looking for all the identical ids that have different x1 variable, although a have two 19 in x1 also have 17 in x1, which make the id "a" different in x1.

Comment: @m0h3n hi! It is irrelevant, I'm looking for difference between x1 variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t      <- table(d$X1, d$ID)
t[t>1] <- 1
t      <- apply(t,2,sum)
t      <- t[t>1]

d1 <- data.frame(ID = names(t))
d1 <- merge(d1, d, by = "ID", all.x=T,all.y=F)
d1 <- unique(d1[,1:2])
d1
```

> ```
>   ID X1
> 1  a 19
> 2  a 16
> 4  b 15
> 5  b 19
> 7  c 16
> 8  c 17
> ```

We can include the 3rd column as well, but you'd need to give some logic to pick which value of it to retain. For instance, there were 2 values of `a` where `X1` was 19, one with `X2` T and one where it was F. To choose between the 2 you could keep the first matching row for `X2`, the last, or choose T above F, etc.

Comment: How is `a 19` included? `19` appears twice for `a`, isn't it?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, 19 appears 2x for `a` and we deduped it as described in the question so that it only shows up 1x in the results.

Answer (score 1):

We can remove the single ids first. Then get a count of the ids left. If there is a single id left we remove it:

```
newdf <- df1[duplicated(df1$ID, fromLast=TRUE),]
tbl <- table(newdf$ID)
newdf[!newdf$ID %in% names(tbl[tbl < 2]),]
#   ID X1    X2
# 1  a 19 FALSE
# 2  b 19 FALSE
# 3  c 16  TRUE
# 4  a 16  TRUE
# 7  b 15 FALSE
# 9  c 17  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
df1[rownames(unique(df1[,c("ID","X1")])),]
```

Comment: That does not produce the desired result in the question. It doesn't filter out the non-repeated ID's like `e`.